# get infos of member on php

Tags: php, mongodb

i have two page :

login.php :

```
<form action="conn.php" method="POST">
    Username:
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username"  />
    Password:
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />    
    <input  name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" value="Login" />
</form>
```

And the PHP

```
    <?php
    $success = "";
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) == "Login" )   
    {
    $username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
    $password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);
    $error = array();
    // Username Validation
    if(empty($username))
    {
    $error[] = " Empty or invalid username ";
    }
    if(empty($password)){
    $error[] = "Enter your password"; 
    }
    if(count($error) == 0){
     $host = 'localhost';  
    $database_name = 'projett';
    $database_user_name = '';  
    $database_password = '';  
     $connection=new MongoClient();
      if($connection){
    // Select Database
    $database = $connection->$database_name;

    // Select Collection
    $collection = $database->reg_users;
    $user_data= array("username" => $username,"password" => md5($pass));
    $result = $collection->findOne($user_data);
    if($result){
    $success = "You are successully loggedIn";
    header("Location: Articles.php");
    } 
    } else {
    die("Mongo DB not installed");
    } 
    }
    } 
    ?>
```

i want display on Member.php the username of the member but when he complete login form a new page open(article.php) with his username

Comment: html form  <form action="conn.php" method="POST">
        Username:
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username"  />
        Password:
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" />    
        <input  name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" value="Login" />
        </form>

Comment: Please don't dump code in comments. Edit your original post to add any new information.

Comment: but when i put html code i have this : username password and i have click to {}

Comment: That is what {} is there for @asm95

Comment: Is your redirect working? If yes, then you could assign your Username to the special `$_SESSION["username"]`  variable. That is available in any file the user navigates to.  Be sure to add session_start().  http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: but when i do this on article.php i have Undefined index: username